# ConversationID is `Nothing` in VSTO Application.ItemSend sub

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I'm trying to create a performance tracking app - which at a basic level will work out how quickly I'm replying to emails.

I think I may be using the wrong "sent item" trigger event though, because the conversation ID is `nothing` for some replies in the below sub `Application_ItemSend`:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Public Shared ConversationThreads As Dictionary(Of String, Date)

    Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(EntryIDCollection As String) Handles Application.NewMailEx
        For Each itemID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
            Dim item = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(itemID)
            If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
                'is it a Tracked Email
                Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
                msg = item
                ConversationThreads.Add(msg.ConversationID, Now())
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_ItemSend(Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            'is it a Tracked Email
            Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
            msg = Item
            For Each tRecipient As Outlook.Recipient In msg.Recipients
                If Not msg.ConversationID Is Nothing AndAlso
                    ConversationThreads.ContainsKey(msg.ConversationID) Then
                      Call OpenCloseThread(msg.ConversationID)
                End If


            Next
        End If

    End Sub

end class
```

Should I be using a different trigger for this sub?

Answer (score 0):

Call `msg.Save()` before reading the `ConversationID` property.

Comment: That hasn't worked. Does it matter that the test "conversation" is between myself and another internal user?

Comment: If you look at the item in the Sent Items folder, does it have ConversationID property set (select the message, click Item button on the OuItlookSpy ribbon, select ConversationID property)?

Comment: Yes, and it matches the conversation ID of the message to which I've replied!

Comment: I can only suggest using Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder instead of the Application.ItemSend